# Pear: Includes are successful but cannot find functions

Tags: php, pear

EDIT: Solution...email is a function within Validate which is a class so you need to access it using:

Validate::email("anemail@email.com");

or

$val = new Validate(); 
$val->email("anemail@email.com");

Thanks red eyes

====================== original question ==============================

Hi,

I'm using Pear and have installed the package Validate to try it out.

Using the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'Validate.php';
email("anemail@email.com");
?>
```

I get the error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function email() in /home/benb/temp/pear.php on line 4
```

If I alter the code to include a non existent extension like require_once 'Validate2.php'; it gives me the error to say it can't find it.
Also, if I view Validate.php I can see the email function within it.

So it seems as though it can find the extension but not the functions within it.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to post Validate.php ?
I think Validate.php it's PHP5 ;)

So it's

```
$val = new validate();
$val->email();
```

Comment: Validate.php is over 1K lines but it's just the standard one downloaded from the Pear repository which can be viewed here:   http://pear.php.net/package/Validate/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_Validate__Validate-0.8.4Validate.php.html#a515

Comment: Do you know what difference between PHP4 and PHP5 ?
PHP5 using class, it's a OOP language :)

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me there. The server is running PHP5.

Comment: Pear it's a library write on PHP5

If you want use a "function" from validate.php, it's necessary to create an interface.
So for call function email.
just use

$val = new validate();
$val->email();

Comment: I know, I've installed the Validate extension

Comment: test
<?php
require_once 'Validate.php';
email("anemail@email.com");
?> 

<?php
include 'Validate.php';
$val = new Validate();
$val->email("anemail@email.com");
?>

Comment: I've got it, thanks Red that's fixed it. Thanks for your help.